# как изменить размер linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтоб вот это подчеркивание было не больше чем само слово ( чтоб оно начиналось с первой буквы и доходила до последний,не реньше и не дальше )
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navlist a:hover span /*, .gorod:hover*/ {
    background-size: 100% 2px;
}

.navlist {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlist a span /*, .gorod*/ {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor);
    background-position: 0% 70%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 0% 2px;
    transition: background-size .9s;
    padding: 1.5em;
}


.navlist a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navlist" >

            <li><a href=""><span>Доставка и оплата</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Условия возврата</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Отзывы</span></a></li>
            /*<li><span class="gorod">Уфа</span></li>*/
            <li class="nomer"><a href=""><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю более корректно делать такой эффект через псевдоэлемент `::before` (или `::after`).
У вас расширяло шире текста, ибо вы давали `background` для `span`, а у него имелся `padding`, я его перенес на `a`, не забыв дать ему `display: block`.

```css
.navlist {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navlist a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

.navlist a span
{
  position: relative;
}

.navlist a span::before
/*, .gorod*/
{
  transition: width .9s;
  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  /* Раскоментировав эту строку вы можете получи эффект справа на лево */
  /* right: 0px; */
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.navlist a:hover span::before
/*, .gorod:hover*/
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navlist">
  <li><a href=""><span>Доставка и оплата</span></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>Условия возврата</span></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>Отзывы</span></a></li>
  <!-- <li><span class="gorod">Уфа</span></li> -->
  <li class="nomer"><a href=""><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
</ul>
```